# Access clone containers produced by FOR LOOP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container and i have cloned it to create 3 more containers. The main reason i used the Clone property was because i didnt want to rewrite the code again and again to make the same containers. Now i want to update different data for the cloned containers. I have managed to pass the heading name for the original container as you can see in the code. Now how do I access my cloned containers and change the data in them. I have put the code which i tried below (failed). When i put data[1],data[0] etc, nothing gets updated.

Current JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var e = $('.column');          //column is the class which contains the container
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    e.clone().insertAfter(e);

  }
  
  
 document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = ("TRAILER 22");
```

Failed Javascript , this does not update anything on the webpage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var e = $('.column');
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    e.clone().insertAfter(e);

  }
  
  var data = document.querySelectorAll(".column");
  
 data[1].document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = ("TRUCK 22");
 

});
```

Comment: When you're cloning an element, you must change all the ids of the cloned elements, because ids work as intended only when they're unique within the document. To find the cloned elements outside of the creation function, you could create an array, and push a clone to that array when cloning.

Comment: Hey thanks a Lot for your reply. Im very new to Javascript and J query. Would you please be able to show what you mean?

Comment: Why are you mixing plain js and jQuery, that makes it a lot harder. As commented before you have a duplicate ID when you clone the element. Thats why it does not work. You can either change it to a class, or change the id when you clone it. Changing it to a class would be the easiest solution i think. If you want to select and change the second .columns heading, you can do that by selecting that element instead of all .column elements (less memory usage)

Comment: Hey @GertB. Thanks for your reply. Is there some example regarding this? Or can you please suggest me what i should search up? Thanks a Lot. Appreciate it !

Comment: Well since I can't see the HTML, I cannot show you how

Comment: hey @GertB. http://jsfiddle.net/JoelCherian/L8wnosmh/ The HTML is here.  Where ever I put the "DATA HERE" is the place i intend to put the data. Thanks a lottt.

Answer (score 0):

You try to do a document call on a element, that is not possible. If you want to change the first column (i switched the code to jQuery, what makes it a lot easier):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var e = $('.column');
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    e.clone().insertAfter(e);

  }
  
  var data = $(document).find(".column:first-of-type");
  
 data.html("TRUCK 22");
 

});
```